# How to use wp_schedule_single_event() from within a class

Tags: php, wordpress

For some reason I am unable to get a scheduled event to trigger using `wp_schedule_single_event`.

```
class My_Class
{
    public function __construct ()
    {
        add_action ( 'after_my_event', array ($this, 'schedule_email_send'), 10, 3 );
        add_action ( 'sendanemail', array ($this, 'send_an_email'), 10, 1 );
    }

    // 3rd party action hook (fires successfully)
    public function schedule_email_send ( $arg1, $arg2, $arg3 )
    {
        wp_clear_scheduled_hook ( 'sendanemail'), array ($arg1) );
        wp_schedule_single_event ( time () + 60, 'sendanemail'), array ($arg1) );
    }

    // Cron task (is never fired)
    function send_an_email ( $arg1 )
    {
        $got_here = true;        // Breakpoint set

        ... code that sends an email.
    {
}
```

With the above code a 3rd party WP plugin successfully fires the `after_my_event` hook and `schedule_email_send()` is executed, but my breakpoint in `send_an_email()` is never reached. I set a breakpoint in that routine and then click on random pages on the site, but the `sendanemail` action never fires. Of course, for testing purposes I'm expecting it to fire in 1 minute.

Does anyone see what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the event firing before the add_action function is called.

For example I have the object created during the 'woocommerce_payment_gateways' hook and the event is being fired independently of this hook, so the event has no reference to the class, the instance, or the action.  I either have to load the class, create the instance, and register it with the action on every page load or I have to convert the method to a global function independent of the original class.